# Some blog posts have borked markdown

Tags: bug, blog, markdown-rendering

Some blog posts have borked markdown. This is what I mean:
[image]
Perhaps someone can update them or change the markdown renderer to support this: `_ hello_` instead of needing this: `_hello_`?

---

`_ hello_` = _ hello_

`_hello_` = *hello*

Comment: Oh and the rep screenshot was removed so we can see the differences

Comment: It doesn't look like a bug to me. It just looks like incorrect usage of markdown syntax. The authors of such posts needed, perhaps, to have more closely checked the preview. I proof-read my posts, although we are all bound to miss something sometimes. If this is not a bug, does that make it a feature-request if you want it to behave differently?

Comment: I've submitted a pull request... I see hichris1234 already did *a lot*!

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ when its merged then post an answer

Answer (score 5):

> Perhaps someone can update them or change the markdown renderer
>
> to support this: `_ hello_` instead of needing this: `_hello_`?

I do not believe this is a bug. I think it is just improper use of markdown syntax. I also do not believe it would be worth the effort of implementing a change to accommodate it. Finally, I might update (edit) such a piece of text, but only if I was already editing it for some other reason... not just to fix some markdown. (Official blog posts, however, are probably worth some extra attention, as you suggest.)

Comment: He's not referring to a standard post, he's referring to posts on the official blog. I agree that it's probably the author's fault, but it's worth fixing even minor errors like this in official blog posts.

Comment: @JeremyBanks Yes, that makes sense.